# Can you execute an Ant task from within a custom Ant task?

Tags: ant

I am writing a custom Ant task to handle some business logic, and I want to call the [Move](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) Ant task.

I presume I would use the Execute java class, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Am I going in the right direction, or can you not call one class from another in an Ant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your task, you wanna call the `Move` task. So you want to move some files.

1. Generally, when you are coding in Java, you should avoid calling built-in Ant tasks, as they usually have poor performance. For example, you can either use `File.renameTo()` method from `java.io.File` or `Files.move()` from `java.nio.file.Files` (JDK7 only).
2. If you do want to take advantage of some Ant things, like `<fileset>`, you may want your task to be able to take `Move` task as a nested task in build xml. Just make your task a `TaskContainer` and do some filtering in its method.
3. Of course, you can also just import the Move task, set all the needed properties, and the call its `execute()` method. But I do not like that.

Comment: Thanks for your response coolcfan. I went with File.renameTo and then ran into recursion problems. So I moved that logic into ANT and used the <move /> task.

Comment: excuse me for the question but i don't understand how to call a task from gradle, i have 'something' task in build.xml, i want to write a task in the gradle's file and put in it the execution of something, how do i do that? somthing.execute()?

Comment: @mautrok don't know gradle myself, but with Java you can `Something sth = new Something()`, and `sth.setXXX(xxx)` and then `sth.execute()`.

Comment: thank you coolcfan, but i have found an answer to this question, and yes it is possible, after the import of the xml file into the gradle's file, it is possible to execute a ant task inside that file simply by using the task.execute() method, where the task is the task you want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer does not answer the original question "Can you execute an Ant task from within a custom Ant task?"

The answer is definitely yes.

Here is an example with Copy. Move is similar. And while `File.renameTo()` may have better performance than calling an Ant Move task, there are definitely reasons why you might want to invoke an Ant task from within a custom Ant task, especially in cases where no suitable JRE alternative exists. The Ant API is very extensive and provides a great number of useful tasks. Furthermore, you may want invoke a custom Ant task from within a different custom Ant task.

See also http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/ja/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/package-summary.html

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet;
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy;
...
// set up the Strings inputPath and outputPath appropriately...
...
try{    
  FileSet inputSet = new FileSet();     // what to copy FROM
  inputSet.setDir(new File(inputPath)); 
  Copy copyTask = new Copy();
  copyTask.setProject(getProject());
  copyTask.setTodir(outputPath);        // where to copy TO
  copyTask.setFailOnError(true);
  copyTask.addFileset(inputSet);
  copyTask.execute();   
}
catch(Exception e){
  String msg = "Exception while invoking Copy task with inputPath=\"" + inputPath + "\" and outputPath=\"" + outputPath + "\": " + e.toString();
  throw new BuildException(msg, e);
}
```